NDSolve does not satisfy initial and boundary condition
I am using NDsolve to solve for a coupled pde system $vA[x,t]$ and $vU[x,t]$.
I have initial condition for $vU[x,0]=2$,
and the boundary condition as $\partial_x vU(0,t)=1$. I have accounted for these in the following code, but the output gives $vU(x,t)$ which is independent of $x$. Could anyone help me with this please?
    sol[b_, m_] := Module[{tmax = 1, dy = 1/10}, xgrid = Range[0, 1, dy];
   nn = Length[xgrid];
   M2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], xgrid, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
   M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
   vA = Table[va[i][t], {i, nn}]; a1 = M1 . vA;
   vU = Table[vu[i][t], {i, nn}]; u1 = M1 . vU;
   mu = RealAbs[u1]^(m - 1);
   eq1 = D[vA, t] - (L'[t]/L[t])  xgrid  a1 + 1/L[t]  M1 . (vA  vU);
   juststh = M1 . (vA);
   eq1[[1]] = 
    D[vA[[1]], t] + 1/L[t]  vA[[1]] + 1/L[t]  2  juststh[[1]];
   eq1[[-1]] = D[vA[[-1]], t];
   eq2 = M1 . (vA  mu  u1);
   (*eq2[[1]]=D[vU[[1]],t]+Exp[-t];*)
   (*eq2[[-1]]=vU[[-1]]-4;*)
   (*eq2[[1]]=D[vU[[1]],t]-1;*)
   
   eq2[[1]] = vU[[1]] - 2;
   eq3 = {L'[t] - vU[[-1]]};
   ic = Join[vA - (L[0] - L[0]  xgrid)^b /. t -> 0, {L[0] - 5}, 
     vU - ((L[0]^(b/m)/(1 - b/m)) (L[0] - L[0]  xgrid)^(1 - b/m) + 
         2 - (L[0]/(1 - b/m))) /. t -> 0];
   (*ic=Join[vA-(L[0]-L[0] xgrid)^b/. t->0,{L[0]-5},vU-(2 xgrid*xgrid+
   xgrid+2)/. t->0];*)var = Join[vA, vU, {L[t]}];
   eqs = Join[eq1, eq2, eq3];
   s = NDSolve[{Table[eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs]}], 
      Table[ic[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[ic]}]}, var, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]; s[[1]]];


sol55 = sol[.5, 1.5];
lstA = Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vA[[i]]} /. sol55, {i, 
   Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0, 1, .02}]; a15 = 
 Interpolation[Flatten[lstA, 1]]; lstU = 
 Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vU[[i]]} /. sol55, {i, Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0,
    1, .02}]; u15 = Interpolation[Flatten[lstU, 1]];
x015[t_] = L[t] /. sol55; xmax = FindMaximum[x015[t], {t, .5}][[1]];
pu15 = Animate[
  Plot[u15[x/x015[t], t], {x, 0, x015[t]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {1.99, 2.01}}], {t, 0, 1}]

